# Simplest Ad Hoc report request in Adwords generates no data. Why?

Tags: reporting, google-ads-api

The following report definition continues to produce no data against all accounts:

```
<reportDefinition xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109">
<selector>
<fields>AccountDescriptiveName</fields>
<fields>AccountId</fields>
</selector>
<reportName>1_91_123_skinny</reportName>
<reportType>ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType>
<dateRangeType>YESTERDAY</dateRangeType>
<downloadFormat>TSV</downloadFormat>
</reportDefinition>
```

I don't get any error messages. Just no data from what would *seem* to be a perfectly legit reportDefinition? I've been using similar ones for some time with no problems. Any ideas?

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for tidying up the tags. Now know what to use next time (and there will be a next time I'm sure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue is with zero-impression behavior:

http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/zero-impression-data-in-adwords-api.html

The ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT doesn't support zero-impression rows, and even if you do have impressions you'll need ensure that you request the Impressions field.

Comment: Hmmm ... so what DOES support zero-impression rows? Or should I be getting the code which SOAPs the account numbers to also get the account names as well?

Comment: Most other reports do support zero impressions, just not the ACCOUNT report. Try doing this with the CAMPAIGN report and include the Impressions field and includeZeroImpression = true.